# Linear Algebra Transformation Question

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Suppose $3\times3$ matrix $A = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$. And suppose $T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ be defined by $T(x) = A(x)$ for every $x$ in $\mathbb R^3$.

1. Find $A^{-1}$ (Easy)
2. Suppose $T^{-1}$ be the inverse transformation $T$, $y = T^{-1}$ and suppose $x = (1,1,1)$. Find this inverse transformation and use it to evaluate $T^{-1}(x)$
3. Suppose $y = T^{-1}(x)$. Evaluate $T(y)$.

Can anyone help me understand 2. and 3.? Is this a trick question since $T(x) = A(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b) you need to know that $T^{-1}(\vec{x}) = A^{-1}\vec{x}$. So you can get $T^{-1}(\vec{x})$ by multiplying the inverse from part (a) with your vector $(1,1,1)^t$.

Yes, (c) is a trick question: remember that the composition of a function and its inverse is always the identity function.
$$
T(\vec{y})=T(T^{-1}(\vec{x})) = A(A^{-1}\vec{x}) = (AA^{-1})\vec{x} = I\vec{x} = \vec{x}
$$

Comment: Thank you !! I have an exam in 25 minutes and this was stumping me.

Comment: vector (1,1,1)^t would be the transposition of the identity matrix, correct? So it would be akin to (A^-1)^t?

Comment: No, I don't think so... The transposition of the identity matrix is the identity matrix, not $(1,1,1)^t$.